# ArrayList en C# .Net Core: "El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres "ArrayList" no se encontro"

Tags: c#, arraylist, .net-core

Estoy intentando instanciar un objeto de la clase ArrayList pero el compilador no me reconoce la clase...
Uso `System.Collections` y `System.Collections.Generic` pero no hay manera...
Todos los ejemplos que veo no hacen nada que yo no este haciendo pero obviamente me estoy dejando algo por el camino...

```
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
```

Error -> `El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres "ArrayList" no se encontro ¿Falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Utilizo List<> pero no se porque no puedo utilizar el ArrayList... es cuestion de curiosidad mas que otra cosa.

Comment: Es una aplicación de tipo consola? Version del framework?

Comment: Hola. Estás implementando una aplicación .NET Core? Si es así, deberías descargarte vía paquete Nuget `System.Collections.NonGeneric`

Comment: Efectivamente Sergio, era por ser una aplicacion de .NET Core
Gracias a todos

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra Deberías poner eso como respuesta (con una breve explicación a ser posible). Como poco te llevarías un +1 de mi parte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si estás implementando una aplicación .NET Core entonces debes descargarte vía paquete Nuget `System.Collections.NonGeneric`.

[`System.Collections.NonGeneric`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.NonGeneric/) provee clases que definen colecciones de objetos no-genéricas más antiguas, como por ejemplo listas, colas, tablas hash y diccionarios. Los desarrolladores deberían optar por las colecciones genéricas en el paquete `System.Collections`.

Algunos de los tipos que incluye:

- System.Collections.ArrayList
- System.Collections.Hashtable
- System.Collections.CollectionBase
- System.Collections.ReadOnlyCollectionBase
- System.Collections.Stack
- System.Collections.SortedList
- System.Collections.DictionaryBase
- System.Collections.Queue
- System.Collections.Comparer
- System.Collections.CaseInsensitiveComparer